# Implement preference item programmatically

Tags: android, layout, preference

I'm trying to implement a preference with a custom layout programmatically.I qundo try to change the components of view they do not appear. Here is the code of preference:

```
public class AvatarPreference extends Preference {

private String name;
private int drawableAvatarDefault;

public AvatarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public AvatarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public AvatarPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AvatarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableAvatarDefault);
    title.setText(name);
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setDrawableAvatarDefault(int drawableAvatarDefault) {
    this.drawableAvatarDefault = drawableAvatarDefault;
}
```

This is the code for setting the preference:

```
  AvatarPreference pref = new AvatarPreference(getActivity());
  pref.setName(pkg.getNome());
  pref.setDrawableAvatarDefault(pkg.getDrawableDefault());
  pref.setLayoutResource(R.layout.pref_child);
```

This is the custom layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg_item_match"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:paddingLeft="16dip"
android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

The layout is composed of an icon and a text. When they are set in the method not onBindView are then displayed. I also tried to redefine the method getView but I get the same result. I hope someone can help me. thanks

EDIT : This is the settings.xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_cat_title_avatar"   android:key="avatars">
<!-- This is the point where the preference is added progammaticamente --> 
</PreferenceCategory>
```

This is the complete method of creation of preference:

```
private void installPreferenceAvatarPackage() {
    AvatarManager.installPackage(getActivity());
    PreferenceCategory category = (PreferenceCategory)findPreference("avatars");
    category.removeAll();
    List<PackageAvatar> packages = AvatarManager.getAvatarPackage();
    for(PackageAvatar pkg : packages) {
        AvatarPreference pref = new AvatarPreference(getActivity());
        pref.setName(pkg.getNome());
        pref.setDrawableAvatarDefault(pkg.getDrawableDefault());
        pref.setLayoutResource(R.layout.pref_child);

        category.addPreference(pref);
    }
}
```

This is what is displayed:

[image]

In the category Avatar appears the ImageView and textView that are set as part of method onBindView AvatarPreference

Comment: `This is the code for setting the preference:`. No. That is code for creating a preference. But where shoud it appear? In which parent screen?

Comment: `When they are set in the method not onBindView are then displayed.`. Sorry but i do not understand what you try to tell here.

Comment: You're right, I mean the creation of a preference.
This preference is displayed in a PreferenceScreen. Do not appear on screen the ImageView and TextView I septum in onBindView. Only the background of the layout is correct. The rest is empty. Forgive my English :-)

Comment: Where are you creating it? And how do you display it in the screen? Please show -a part of- your preferences  xml where you define your custom preference.

Comment: I added a picture. thanks

Comment: `<!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->` ?? What do you mean by that? You suggested that this was the layout for your custom preference.

Comment: `This is the custom layout xml:`. You mean pref_child.xml ?

Comment: `AvatarPreference pref = new AvatarPreference(getActivity());` In what kind of component are you using that code? As getActivity() is possible.

Comment: Mmm.. Yes you you have to do such i saw now. Sorry cannot get this going either.